# how to check if item is selected from a comboBox in C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm pretty new here.

I have a form, and want to check if the user filled it in correctly.  In the form there's a combo box; how can I build the "if" statement for checking whether the user picked an item  from it ?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English, it's not my mother tongue. :)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use:

```
if(comboBox.SelectedIndex > -1) //somthing was selected
```

To get the selected item you do:

```
Item m = comboBox.Items[comboBox.SelectedIndex];
```

As Matthew correctly states, to get the selected item you could also do

```
Item m = comboBox.SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is the perfect coding which checks whether the Combo Box Item is Selected or not

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Item is Selected"); 
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Item Selected is:" + comboBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: Who said 1st entry was null in OP?

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be using Windows Forms. Look at the [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx) or [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) properties.

```
if (this.combo1.SelectedItem == MY_OBJECT)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
    //Done
}
```

It Works,, Try it

Comment: i believe this does the opposite

Comment: That is the exact opposite of what the OP described.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (combo1.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    // do something
}
```

if any item is selected selected index will be greater than -1

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if(combo1.Text == "")
{

}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation on how it will solve the OP problem and how it is better than the other answers?

Comment: Its not better than the other answers necessarily.  It is not entirely clear what the OP was asking.  This is a direct way to use the combobox text property to determine what the user has selected and compare it to an expected value of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using this null comparison works well:

```
if (Combobox.SelectedItem != null){
   //Do something
}
else{
  MessageBox.show("Please select a item");
}
```

This will only accept the selected item and no other value which may have been entered manually by the user which could cause validation issues.