# ComboBox validation

Tags: c#, combobox

I am doing a project in c# and need to validate two `ComboBoxes`. If the two `ComboBoxes` show the same value, an error message should appear saying that you cannot select the same value.

```
private void btnBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbDeaprture == cmbDestination);
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot have the same Destination as Departure");
}
```

That's my code, but does not seem to work. Any help? Im new to c# so still learning.

Comment: It should be `if (cmbDeaprture.SelectedItem == cmbDestination.SelectedItem)` and also remove stray `;` at then end of your `if`.

Comment: Besides using the `.SelectedValue` property as suggested in the answers to remedy your problem, you can also use the built-in validation via the `IDataErrorInfo` interface on your data object and validate your combo boxes via `{Binding ... ValidatesOnDataErrors=true}` to just highlight the combo box and get a tooltip with the errors. I found that approach much less cumbersome than showing message boxes that interrupt the user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check if item is selected from a comboBox in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687889/how-to-check-if-item-is-selected-from-a-combobox-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are comparing comboBoxes instead of selected values.
Also, in your case the `if-statement` body is empty, because you have a `;` after. 
Use [SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property to get a selected item.

```
private void btnBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbDeaprture.SelectedItem == cmbDestination.SelectedItem)
         MessageBox.Show("Cannot have the same Destination as Departure");
}
```

If you want to check that user has selected something, you need to check that `SelectedItem != null`. You can add it using `&&` operator.

```
if (cmbDeaprture.SelectedItem != null && cmbDeaprture.SelectedItem == cmbDestination.SelectedItem)
```

Comment: The message box appears even when nothing has been selected? Edit: It ok, i got it. Thanks very much your code worked

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
private void btnBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbDeaprture.SelectedValue== cmbDestination.SelectedValue);
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot have the same Destination as Departure");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbDeaprture.Text.Equals(cmbDestination.Text)){
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot have the same Destination as Departure");
    }
}
```