# How to test which combobox has been most recently changed? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Is there a way to check to see which combobox which value has been most recently changed?

[how to check if item is selected from a comboBox in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687889/how-to-check-if-item-is-selected-from-a-combobox-in-c-sharp)

I know you can do this,

```
if (MyComboBox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

The problem I am having is that I am combining Event Handlers in to one handler due to the amount of comboboxes and having one event for each combobox really is not practical if I can help it.

Is there a way to have a variable assigned giving you the name of the combobox which value has been most recently changed? Or will I have to use individual event handlers for each combobox?

Comment: Single Event Handler is fair. could you please post the code for that Event Handler

Comment: @un-lucky, Yes each combobox is uniquely named and I am using databinding `SelectionChanged="" ` property to call the single event handler. Not sure the code will help much as it is just you standard event. `private void comboboxChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)`

Comment: Good take a look into the answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually It will be very easy to track most recent combobox change when you using single event handler for all combobox. You can do by following way.

```
string lastComboName=""; // define global variable  
//common event handler for all combobox 
 private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    var cmb = (ComboBox)sender; 
    lastComboName = cmb.Name;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope that each comboBox having an unique name, then we can use those name to identify which one is the sender of event: Now consider the following code for this:

```
private void CboFirst_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox selctedComboBox = sender as ComboBox;
    string ComboName = selctedComboBox.Name;
    // Do something
}
```

Now tracking the last updated ComboBox, You can achieve this by keeping a blobal variable and update it in every trigger so Every time it holds the Latest value( the name of the combobox)