# How do I prevent fire focus on click of ComboBox in WPF when the item is not in the list?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, lost-focus

I use C# WPF

**What I need :**

When focus lost on ComboBox , check if ComboBox has no a valid item Show a Error .

**What I did :**

*MyXAML :*

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="SecoundCombo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="359" LostFocus="SecoundCombo_LostFocus" IsEditable="True">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Jack" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="402"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Sam" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="402"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="John" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="402"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

*My Code Behind :*

```
    namespace TEST
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static bool ComboisChoosedItem_Valid(ComboBox CMB)
        {
            bool st = true;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CMB.Text.Trim()) && CMB.SelectedIndex > -1 && CMB.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                if (CMB.Items.OfType<ComboBoxItem>().Any(cbi => cbi.Content.Equals(CMB.Text)))
                {
                    //ComboBox is Not Empty is Correct Item Selected
                    st = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //ComboBox Is Empty Or Not Correct Item Selected
                st = false; 
            }
            return st;
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    

        private void SecoundCombo_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource != sender) return;
            if (ComboisChoosedItem_Valid(SecoundCombo) == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please choose valid item from list");
                SecoundCombo.IsDropDownOpen = true;
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

**My Problem :**

In this case when I click on the ComboBox the LostFocus event will fire

but it seems didn't happened , in google search I found this :

**What have I tried :**

```
 var textBox = SecoundCombo.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", SecoundCombo) as TextBox;
        if (textBox.IsFocused != true)
        {
            if (ComboisChoosedItem_Valid(SecoundCombo) == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Choose an item");
                SecoundCombo.IsDropDownOpen = true;
            }
        }
```

none of them work

Please help

Comment: You can only select items that are in the `Items` collection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what are you asking, but i think that this might help you -
[how to check if item is selected from a comboBox in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687889/how-to-check-if-item-is-selected-from-a-combobox-in-c-sharp/5687944)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for your help but my problem is clear ! that is why lost focus will go when I click on combobox and lost focus not happened yet

Comment: I know how should I check validation I can't use it in lost focus event